# Show inequality for positive real numbers

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

If $x,y$ are positive real numbers then we have that $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}$$ right? But how can we show that?

I have tried the following but I don't think that this is the way we should go.
\begin{align*}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x + y}} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}=\frac{\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{xy}} & \iff \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x + y}}\right)^2 < \left(\frac{\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{xy}}\right)^2 \\ & \iff \frac{1}{x + y} <\frac{x+y+2\sqrt{xy}}{xy} \\ & \iff  xy<(x+y)(x+y+2\sqrt{xy}) \\ & \iff xy<x^2+xy+2x\sqrt{xy}+xy+y^2+2y\sqrt{xy}\\ & \iff 0<x^2+2(x+y)\sqrt{xy}+xy+y^2\end{align*}

Comment: What's wrong with that? Maybe a little messy, but not complicated.

Comment: If you prefer, multiply by $\sqrt {x+y}$ at the start to see that the desired inequality is the same as $1<\sqrt {1+\frac yx} +\sqrt {1+\frac xy}$ which is obvious (both summands are $>1$ separately).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: there are a couple of typos that make your comment hard to read. First, you introduce $u, v$ but then you speak again of $x, y$, and second, the inequalities with the "max" seem to be reversed. PS: oh i see you added an answer with the corrected version, you may ignore my comment

Comment: Yep, thought I deleted that comment. Sorry, @GiuseppeNegro Made it an answer instead. The deleted the answer because the **right** answer was so easy.

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In fact, for $x,y>0$, one has
$$ x+y>x \Longrightarrow \sqrt{x+y}>\sqrt x \Longrightarrow\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y}}<\frac1{\sqrt x}<\frac1{\sqrt x}+\frac1{\sqrt y.}$$

Comment: Indeed, so simple!

Comment: This is definitely the *right* right answer.  In general, if $f:\mathbb R^+\to\mathbb R^+$ is strictly decreasing, $f(x+y)<f(x)+f(y).$

Comment: In my last comment, you don't even need strictly. You have $f(x+y)\leq f(x)<f(x)+f(y).$

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! :-)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 4):

$f(x) = 1/\sqrt{x}$ is *strictly convex* on $(0, \infty)$, so that
$$
f\left( \frac{x+y}{2}\right) < \frac 12 \left( f(x) + f(y) \right) \, ,
$$
for $0 < x < y$, this gives the stronger inequality
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+y}}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\right) \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The stronger inequality in the answer by *Martin R* can be proved by applying $a^2+b^2>2ab,$ for $0<a<b,$ twice. For $0<u<v$ we get $${1\over \sqrt{u^4+v^4}}<{1\over \sqrt{2}uv}={1\over 2\sqrt{2}}2{1\over u}{1\over v}<{1\over 2\sqrt{2}}\left ({1\over u^2}+{1\over v^2}\right )$$ Now plug in $x=u^4$ and $y=v^4.$